# How to print lines number 15 and 25 out of each 50 lines?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a large file and I would like print from each sequential 50 lines , the **15th** and **25th** lines.

```
sed -n '15,25p' inputfile
```

How to modify this command to print only lines 15 and 25 and to loop over each 50 lines in the file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
awk 'NR % 50 == 15 || NR % 50 == 25'
```

would be the obvious portable way.

Note a GNU `sed` alternative:

```
sed '15~50b;25~50b;d'
```

With any `sed`, you can always do:

```
sed -n 'n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;p;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;p;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n'
```

(get next line 14 times, print, next line 10 times, print, next line 25 times, back to the next cycle (which grabs the missing extra line to make 50)).

Answer (score 10):

this is a job for `awk`

```
awk '(NR%50==15) || (NR%50==25)' inputfile
```

edit: I was mislead by sed instruction in OP.

Answer (score 9):

With `perl`

1) Similar to the `awk` solution, `$.` variable stores line number

```
$ seq 135 | perl -ne 'print if $.%50==15 || $.%50==25'
15
25
65
75
115
125
```

2) Check against list of line numbers, easier to extend

```
$ seq 135 | perl -ne 'print if grep {$_==$.%50} (15,25)'
15
25
65
75
115
125

$ seq 135 | perl -ne 'print if grep {$_==$.%50} (15,25,32)'
15
25
32
65
75
82
115
125
132
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach using awk, based on [Sundeep's idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326007/67817) of using a list:

```
awk 'BEGIN { a[15] a[25] }; NR % 50 in a'
```

Set keys in the array `a` based on the lines you want to print. Print lines where `NR % 50` matches one of the keys in the array.

---

To give some indication of the performance, I timed this approach and compared with the other answers, taking an average of the `user` time for 3 runs.

**0.276s**

```
$ time awk 'BEGIN { a[15] a[25] }; NR % 50 in a' <(seq 1000000) > /dev/null
```

**0.374s**

```
$ time awk 'NR % 50 == 15 || NR % 50 == 25' <(seq 1000000) > /dev/null
```

**0.384s**

```
$ time perl -ne 'print if $.%50==15 || $.%50==25' <(seq 1000000) > /dev/null
```

**0.542s**

```
$ time perl -ne 'print if grep {$_==$.%50} (15,25)' <(seq 1000000) > /dev/null
```