# How to select certain lines (n, n+4, n+8, n+12...) from the file?

Tags: text-processing

Input:

```
1
hgh
h2b
h4h
2
ok
koko
lkopk
3
uh
ju
nfjvn
4
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

So, I need to have only 1st, 5th, 9th, 13th value of the file in the output file. How to do this?

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325985/how-to-print-lines-number-15-and-25-out-of-each-50-lines with GNU sed, you can do `sed -n '1~4p'`

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/396536/how-to-keep-only-every-nth-line-of-a-file

Answer (score 29):

Using AWK:

```
awk '!((NR - 1) % 4)' input > output
```

Figuring out how this works is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thanks for this short awk course!

Comment: `NR % 4 == 1` would be more legible IMO.

Comment: Agreed @Stéphane; this is probably questionable on my part, but for potentially homework questions I try to obfuscate my answers a little...

Comment: @StephenKitt obfuscate your answers? Really? This is not the place to do that.

Answer (score 23):

Using `split`  (GNU coreutils):

```
split -nr/1/4 input > output
```

- `-n` generate `CHUNKS` output files

and `CHUNKS` as

- `r/K/N` use round robin distribution and only output Kth of N to stdout without splitting lines/records

Comment: Mind blown.  Answers like this are why I love this SE.  Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed '1~4!d' < input > output
```

With standard `sed`:

```
sed -n 'p;n;n;n' < input > output
```

With `1` and `4` in `$n` and `$i` variables:

```
sed "$n~$i!d" # GNU only
```

```
awk -v n="$n" -v i="$i" 'NR >= n && (NR % i) == (n % i)'
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding the obligatory perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. % 4 == 1' input > output
```

Answer (score 4):

Python version, just for fun:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        if i%4 == 0:
            print(line.strip())
```

Comment: `enumerate(f)` should be able to do the job while consuming less memory

Comment: @iruvar That's so neat!  Never realized that before; will be using in the future.  Feel free to edit it into this answer; I'm not really going to maintain it with optimizations since the other Bash answers (especially [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/517965/99989)) are definitely the way to go.

Comment: If you're going to use `readlines` (hence slurping the whole file into memory), you can use `f.readlines()[::4]` to get every fourth line. So you can use `print(''.join(f.readlines()[::4]))`.

Answer (score 3):

`POSIX sed`: this method uses the posixly sed and so can be run everywhere, or atleast those seds that respect posix.

```
 $ sed -ne '
   /\n/!{
    H;s/.*//;x
   }

   :loop
       $bdone
       N;s/\n/&/4
       tdone
   bloop

   :done
   s/.//;P
 ' input.file
```

Another is a programmatic sed code generation for scalability purposes:

```
$ code=$(yes n | head -n 4 | paste -sd\; | sed s/n/p/)
$ sed -ne "$code" input.file
```

`Perl`: we fill-up array A till it is 4 in size. Then we print its first element and also clear out the array.

```
$ perl -pe '
   $A[@A] = @A ? <> : $_ while @A < 4;
   $_ = (splice @A)[0];
' input.file
```

Answer (score 1):

Call with `scriptname filename skip` (4 in your case)
It works by pulling `iter` lines from the top of the file and then only outputting the last.  It then increments `iter` by `skips` and repeats as long as the value of `iter` hasn't exceeded the `lines` in `file`.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
lines=`wc -l < "$file"`
skips="$2" || "4"
iter=1
while [ "$iter" -le "$lines" ]; do
 head "$file" -n $iter | tail -n 1
 iter=$(( $iter + $skips ))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
mapfile -t lines < input
for (( i=0; i < ${#lines[@]}; i+=4 ))
do printf "%s\n" "${lines[$i]}"
done
```

[mapfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) is a builtin added in Bash 4 which reads standard input into an array, here named `lines`, with one line per entry. The `-t` option strips the final newlines.

If you want to print every fourth line starting from line 4, then you can do that in one command using `mapfile`'s callback option `-C`, which runs the provided code every so many lines, with the interval given by `-c`. The current array index and the next line to be assigned are given to the code as arguments.

```
mapfile -t -c4 -C 'printf "%.0s%s\n"' < input
```

This uses the `printf` builtin; the format code `%.0s` suppresses the first argument (the index), so only the line is printed.

You could use the same command to print every fourth line starting from line 1, 2, or 3, but you'd have to prepend 3, 2, or 1 lines to `input` before feeding it to `mapfile`, which I think is more trouble than it's worth.

This also works:

```
mapfile -t lines < input
printf "%s%.0s%.0s%.0s\n" "${lines[@]}"
```

Here, `printf` consumes four entries of the array `lines` at a time, only printing the first and skipping the other three with `%.0s`. I don't like this since you have to manually fiddle with the format string for different intervals or starting points.